# C# GUI is freezing when try to read and decode big files

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, datagridview

I have developed a GUI winforms to read and decode the CSV file and save it in Excel and CSV format. I am displaying the decoded data in datagridview. Everything is working fine but for some freaking reason GUI is freezing because of large files or may be the weather is cold here. Its still does what it suppose to do but displays (software not responding). I have used Thread and background work as well but still no hope. here is the code. please share any help

```
 public delegate void UpdatingTable();
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke(new UpdatingTable(DecodingData));
    }


    private void cnvrtB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Enabled = true;
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        saveB.Visible = true;
        cnvrtB.Enabled = false;
        label5.Visible = true;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        //DecodingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartDecoding));
        //DecodingThread.IsBackground = true;

        //if (!(DecodingThread.IsAlive) || DecodingThread == null)
        //{
        //    progressBar1.Enabled = true;
        //    progressBar1.Visible = true;
        //    saveB.Visible = true;
        //    cnvrtB.Enabled = false;
        //    label5.Visible = true;
        //    Thread.Sleep(2000);
        //    DecodingThread.Start();
        //}
        //else if (DecodingThread.IsAlive)
        //{
        //    progressBar1.Enabled = true;
        //    progressBar1.Visible = true;
        //    saveB.Visible = true;
        //    cnvrtB.Enabled = false;
        //    label5.Visible = true;
        //    DecodingThread.Resume();
        //}           

    }


    private void StartDecoding()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Invoke(new UpdatingTable(DecodingData));
    }
    public void DecodingData()
    {
        try
        {
            //delete old records                
            records.Clear();

            //get records from converter
            if (VersionNumber == 1)
            {
                records.AddRange(LogEventDecode.getRecords());

            }
            else if (VersionNumber == 0)
            {
                records.AddRange(LogEventDecode.getRecordsOld());
            }

            //create datatable for records
            table = new System.Data.DataTable("data");
            //create columns
            table.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(System.DateTime));
            table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(System.DateTime));
            table.Columns.Add("dt", typeof(System.DateTime));
            table.Columns.Add("User", typeof(System.String));
            table.Columns.Add("SourceInformation", typeof(System.String));
            table.Columns.Add("SourceType", typeof(System.String));
            table.Columns.Add("SourceCondition", typeof(System.String));
            table.Columns.Add("securityLevel", typeof(System.String));
            table.Columns.Add("AdditionalInformation", typeof(System.String));
            table.Columns.Add("RubCondition", typeof(System.String));

            //populate datatable
            foreach (LogRecord r in records)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                row["Time"] = r.Time;
                row["Date"] = r.Date;
                row["dt"] = r.dt;
                row["User"] = r.User;
                row["SourceInformation"] = r.SourceInformation;
                row["SourceType"] = r.SourceType;
                row["SourceCondition"] = r.SourceCondition;
                row["securityLevel"] = r.SecurityLevel;
                row["AdditionalInformation"] = r.AdditionalInformation;
                row["RubCondition"] = r.RubCondition;
                table.Rows.Add(row);
                //DecodingCount++;
                //label5.Text = "Decoded" + DecodingCount + " out of Total Logs " + records.Count;
            }
            view = new DataView(table);

            //bind to grid                

            //DecodingThread.Abort();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageB.Show("Please make sure you have Imported the File \nOR\n The imported file is not corrupted.", "File Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            cnvrtB.Enabled = true;
        }

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        logRecordBindingSource.DataSource = view;


        cnvrtB.Enabled = true;

        progressBar1.Visible = false;
        progressBar1.Enabled = false;
        label5.Visible = false;
    }
```

the given example displayed both threading and background method

Thanks

Comment: Where do you call StartDecoding from? It has Sleep that would freeze UI if called from UI thread

Comment: why are u calling `Invoke` in the background worker?

Comment: calling invoke to update the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call `Invoke` in your background worker, as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx), here is what `Invoke` does:

> Executes a delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

So your background worker is executing the code on the control's (i.e. GUI) thread

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I use the delegate and how it would prevent the GUI to freeze.. Please answer this dumb question

Comment: Not sure I understand your question - you can call `DecodeingData` in `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` and then handle the background worker's `RunWorkerCompleted` event to update the GUI once the reading is finished .. does that answer your question?

Comment: thanks, this is what i was thinking . Hopefully it would work. Thanks @KMoussa

Comment: Did you check, at what exact moment the app freezes? Because it may get frozen when UI starts binding DataView to a grid, and this is a long process. You may try to embrace this bind call to Begin/EndUpdate